# onclick event from XML Nodes

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, dom-events, xul

My documents are a mixture of XML and HTML tags, where HTML tags are pulled from xhtml namespace and mine are from various namspaces.
I want to take user interaction events from XML Nodes of my document.
I first tried `<do:landingTime xhtml:onclick="fnc">20:48:29.45</do:landingTime>` with no Luck. But `<xhtml:span onclick="fnc">` works.
So is there any solution/tricks/hacks/backdoor to take events from my XML Nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the click events using Javascript and accept answers to your questions.

Comment: Can you give a bit more explanation ??

Comment: You can use Javascript to attach event handlers by calling `attachEvent` / `addEventListener`.  The simplest way to do this is using [jQuery](http://jquery.com).

Comment: But jQuery doesn't seem to work if I pull html tags from xhtml namespace

Comment: You need to escape the `:`, like this: `$('ns\\:tag')`